# I improved my downvoted answer, now what?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, answers, downvotes

I answered a question, but my answer was downvoted. The downvoter explained what was wrong with the question in a comment. I edited the answer to fixed those problems.

But unfortunately, the list of answers is sorted by votes, so my answer is hidden at the bottom. Even more, downvoted answers are faded-out to signal that they're not good answers. I feel like it's simply too late, that nobody is going to notice my improved answer and upvote it. How should I draw attention to a downvoted answer after it's improved?

Comment: You could wait, like the rest of us. Consider deleting some if they are dreadful.

Comment: When did you edit it? How many extra views did the question get in the meantime? These things take a little while...

Comment: While I think downvoters have the responsibility to check if the post improved, the site seems doesn't have related features to notice downvoters

Comment: I'm not going to revisit every down-vote i make to check of the poster has improved it -- so think carefully before answering in the first place,

Comment: This is why I comment first and down-vote later. Basically I make a comment telling the OP what the problem is, if they didn't fix it after a while (*or have read my comment but didn't fix or disagreed*) I come back and down-vote.

Comment: One thing that you can do is to comment to the person that left the original comment to let them know that you've improved your answer.  This way, they know to come back and look, and you might be able to convert that downvote into an upvote.  Make sure to address them by @name to make sure that the comment gets sent to them.  If you had multiple commenters, simply reply to each commenter separately.  Only do this after you're sure that the answer is really good, because you won't get them to come back a 3rd time.

Answer (score -19, accepted):

Reply to the downvoter in a comment, so that (s)he will retract the downvote after discovering that you improved your answer.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447301/regex-to-get-first-character-in-a-string-that-isnt-in-a-b-c-or/38447343#comment64301365_38447343) ([screenshot for those with <10K rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdfQK.jpg))

Comment: Voting is anonymous, how would you do that?

Comment: You can't even know who it was that downvoted him. Chances are they've long since forgotten about him and his question and care absolutely not.